# base.css is not get imported into the page?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am trying to override the class generated by page-down app and the django-crispy-forms . But the indentation that is expected through overrideing class is not working.

**base.html**(initially)

```
...
<link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/base.css" %}'>
<style>
{% block style %}{% endblock style %}
</style>
{% block head_extra %}{% endblock head_extra %}
...
```

**base.css**

```
h1 {
    color: #777777;
}
```

**post_forms.html**

```
{%extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block head_extra %}
{{form.media}}
{% endblock head_extra %}
...
```

By using the inspect feature in chrome I can spot the class that causes the indentation

```
<div class="wmd-panel">
</div>
```

The code CSS given below is automatically generated one

```
.wmd-panel {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

*But after making changes to css/base.css , there is no class named wmd-panel from the file base.css in the styles tab of the chrome. And the changes made are not reflected in the webpage.*

**base.css**

```
h1 {
    color: #777777;
}

.wmd-panel{
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

This is what expected in chrome inspect styles tab

```
.wmd-panel {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
}
```

This above class is from basic.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clean the chrome cache and check again. Sometimes it just does not update the code and you are just viewing the old CSS even you have made changes to it.

```
Settings>Advanced>ClearBrowsingData>
```

and delete all **Cached images and files**

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `{% load static %}`? Sometimes you just forget that. And often you miss `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in your settings.

Comment: It is added in base.html file